# Oracle SQL statement without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to write a SQL statement to return 2 columns, however there cannot be duplicates in either of these columns.  For example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |        A         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          11         |        B         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |        C         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          13         |        A         | <--- Don't return
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Using distinct doesn't work, since the row highlighted above is distinct.  It also doesn't matter which of the duplicates is returned.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  It feels as though I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is (13, A) invalid but not (10, A)?

Comment: And what would happen if you had `11/C`?

Comment: I may have worded it a bit strongly!  Neither are invalid, I just want to see one (doesn't matter which).  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: And what would happen if you had 11/A again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to make row number by `col2` and get `rn = 1` data row.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col1 int,
   col2 varchar(5)
);


insert into t values (10,'A');
insert into t values (11,'B');
insert into t values (12,'C');
insert into t values (13,'A');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col1) rn
    FROM T t1
)t1
WHERE t1.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7b5db/3/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
|------|------|
|   10 |    A |
|   11 |    B |
|   12 |    C |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the lowest value from the first column, do:

```
SELECT MIN(column1), column2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY column2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not posible in one query, because each column have different number of unique values